# how to access linux files using samba from windows without username and password authentication

Tags: samba, authentication

I am not able to access Linux files from windows using samba without username and password authentication. It is always asking for username and password.

Is there a way to access Linux files without any authentication (not even first time) so that Anyone can access.

Is there any suggestion?

from my `smb.conf` file.

I have put,

```
security = share
guest account = nobody

[home]
  comment = Home Directory
# browseable=no here hides homes,but displays a scetion with username;(refer man
  browseable = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
  path = /
  guest ok = yes
# valid users = %S
```

Answer (score 1):

add a guest account to your samba configurastion as described here:
https://www.debuntu.org/samba-how-to-share-files-for-your-lan-without-userpassword/

```
security = share
#...
guest account = nobody
#...
[Guest Share]
        comment = Guest access share
        path = /path/to/dir/to/share
        browseable = yes
        read only = yes
        guest ok = yes
```